# Angular 2 - encrypt password while sending from angular 2 to web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am new in Angular 2 development.In my application I have login module where passing username and password[Plain Text] to Web APi controller for authentication from angular service class.

Below is my angular 2 service method which calls web api.

```
authenticate(model) {        
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charste=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:24314/api/Users/', body, options)
        .map(response => response.json()).catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

Somehow I want to encrypt this password field while sending to web api.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To pass credentials to your server, send them over HTTPS; no needs to encrypt them yourself. Sends everything to HTTPS; today HTTP is no longer a credible option.

The credentials should not appear in your code, but be entered in a form by the user. You get them in memory and send them to the server. The ideal would be that the server exchanges them for an authentication token, so you could next store this token on the client (in the localstorage for example). You could then authenticate your user to the server by sending the token to each request (always on HTTPS of course).

Comment: yeah `https` is one of the best option no doubt :)

Comment: @gentiane. Totally agree with HTTPS option.

Answer (score -1):

```js
authenticate(model) {        
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charste=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    model.pass = yourEncryptionFunction(model.pass, 'superStringPass');

    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:24314/api/Users/', body, options)
        .map(response => response.json()).catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}

yourEncryptionFunction(password: string, cryptoKey: string): string {
    // .. do something here.. use a lib or just add a static value..
    return ....;
}
```

Problem is, everybody can see your encryption mehtod and its used crypto-key or whatever.. so there is no real benefit of doing it. :)

Interesting libraries:

- http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/
- https://openpgpjs.org/

Answer (score -1):

The Best and simple aproach to encrypt password is javascript btoa method , you can use it like this

```
authenticate(model) {        
    let data = btoa(model.user_name + ':' + model.password);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charste=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:24314/api/Users/', body, options)
        .map(response => response.json()).catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

By using which you dont have to use any third party library for encryption or something like this
for more info refer here

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp

Comment: btoa is absolutely not used to encrypt whatever. It just encodes a string in base64, and anybody can decode it.

Comment: yes i know anybody can decode it, but not a normal user, and yes there are no of website who are using same technique too. and this is just a option

Comment: In your post you said that btoa can encrypt password. btoa is not an encryption algorithm, it is just a encoding algorithm. That is completely different. And anybody can decode it.

Comment: yeah may be mine wording can be wrong, yes btoa is an encoding algorithm. you are right

Comment: @gentiane Thanks for your input and suggestion but just saw below answers and it would be good to use HTTPS.

Comment: @pushkar it's fine but my answer is not wrong so why downvote ?? May i know

Comment: @PardeepJain - this is about encryption not encode and in your solution you're combining both username and password in parameter. End API is able to take them only as individual parameters.How to decode at the API level if use your solution. Btw I undo my vote. Thanks